# How do I use http://example.com instead of http://example.com/Example/?

Tags: java, tomcat6

Here `/Example` is my .war file and all file in it in .jsp format. 
I have access my .war via `http://example.com:8080`.

How can I access it via `http://example.com`?

Comment: You've said you have access on `http://example.com:8080`, but in your title you said you want to use `http://example.com` instead of `http://example.com/Example/`, not instead of `http://example.com:8080`.

Comment: that is it that you want exactly, to change the port or what ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the anwser in the Tomcat documentation at: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: This is not helpful for the OP. Try to incorporate the relevant parts of the answer in your post, so your answer remains valid, even if the linked resource goes down.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

1) Edit the conf/server.xml file in your tomcat installation folder. (I assume you are using tomcat, if not - look for an equivalent file for your web server). Here is a sample entry (edit the port here)

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Restart tomcat.

2) The second way is to use re-directs or url-rewrites to forward traffic to port 8080 to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Change the http connector port from 8080 to 80 in your tomcat's server.xml. Look for `<Connector` tag and there you will see `port` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Rename your WAR file to ROOT.war, the name ROOT for tomcat means that it is the root context (all capital letters) and the name is reserved for such this purpose.  See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming

Next, change the listener port in conf/server.xml from 8080 to 80.